# why data is trimmed after passing value to textbox from database?

Tags: php, mysql, validation

Am using php, mysql. When i fetch a data from the mysql database to a text box to update, only half of the data is sent , for example if a student name is "john doe", after i query the database and set the value to a textbox from PHP, only "John" appears in textbox.

What would cause this problem , am not able to detect.

In database the name is stored completely.

here is php script

EDIT:

```
$srch = mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['srch']);

$query = mysql_query("select * from X where htno='$srch' or studname like '%$srch%' ");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$data = "";

if($row){

$data .= '<table border="0" class="data_display">
<tr>
<th>HAll Ticket No:</th><th>Category</th><th>Centercode</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>'.$row['htno'].'<input type="hidden" id="htno" value="'.$row['htno'].'" /></td><td>'.$row['category'].'</td><td>'.$row['centercode'].'</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Student Name</th><th>Center name</th><th>Student code</th><th>Score</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" class="scoretxt" id="category" value='.$row['studname'].'/></td><td>'.$row['centername'].'</td><td>'.$row['studentcode'].'</td>
<td></tr>
</table>; }
```

Any help is appreciated. Tnx

Comment: That depends entirely on the PHP script you're using; could you add that to the question?

Comment: u mean u want the script @DavidThomas ?

Comment: We need to see what's going on, so yeah; we'll need to see your PHP script (or at least the relevant portion(s) of it, that handles the retrieval and display).

Comment: Maybe your database field has a length of 4?

Comment: @jlcd in database it is stored properly type is varchar (255)... ll update in question though

Comment: Track down where the problem is. Is the correct data written to the database in the script? Is the correct data in the data base? Is the correct data read back from the database? You need to localize the problem.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz tnx, the only problem is , it is returning only fist half of text i,e the one before space.. so am not getting it ... :(

Comment: Your code seems correct. Are you SURE you're looking the right table/value? What's the htno field type/length? And what's the expected value you want to see in the input?

Comment: Could you print the output of ` $srch = mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['srch']);

    $query = mysql_query("select * from X where htno='$srch' or studname like '%$srch%' ");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    print_r($row)'
`  to your question ?

Comment: yes, htno is varchar(20), engine is Myisam...

Comment: @JackBrown yes am getting the full text after printing the query...

Comment: @sree : for which field are you getting less name? $row['studname'] or $row['centername']. I am sure you are looking at the INCORRECT variable i.e. full name is there in variable $row['fullName'] & you might be looking at $row['firstName']... Hope you got what I meant to say...

Comment: @FahimParkar yeh, i got u.. but its perfect ..perhaps ll put the edited script again..

Comment: @sree : Instead of `<td><input type="text" class="scoretxt" id="category" value='.$row['studname'].'/></td>` can you put `<td>$row['studname']</td>` and let me know what you get?? Full text or half text?

Comment: am getting full. text.perhaps am missing double quot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the quotation marks around the student name.

`<input type="text" class="scoretxt" id="category" value='.$row['studname'].'/>`

is generating `<input type="text" class="scoretxt" id="category" value=John Doe />`, which only shows up as "John".

It should be

`<input type="text" class="scoretxt" id="category" value="'.$row['studname'].'"/>`

producing `<input type="text" class="scoretxt" id="category" value="John Doe" />`

HTML is very forgiving, so little things like this are difficult to catch.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this code has no problems related to your problem (though it has SQL injections, and XSS vulnerabilities). What you need is called debugging. First check that the problem is not in the return from MySQL (with var_dump($row)), if everything is correct there assume the problem is afterwards, otherwise - before. Use var_dump() and check places that may affect the student name. I don't see any others in this code, so I think this piece will work if $row is ok.

Comment: $row is throwing all the data... so am confused their, when i append the value to textbox only first pice of info is shown.. so need to find that out.. .. tnx